# Extract dataset from github.com using api

Tags: github, github-api

I need to get dataset containing 10000 public user's accounts from [github.com](http://github.com) which use Scala. Is there any way to perform it via api?

Comment: To get all users https://developer.github.com/v3/users/#get-all-users